# Microsoft Form recognizer api returning 3003 OCR extraction error

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I m playing around with the Form Recognizer API and whereas i m able to send a jpg image for analysis, using the analyze form method, when i try to get the result i am getting the error below:

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 53
apim-request-id: 2e27c646-6935-4d3c-85e7-c4f51efd3744
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-content-type-options: nosniff
Date: Fri, 07 Feb 2020 13:56:06 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
  "status": "failed",
  "createdDateTime": "2020-02-07T13:52:29Z",
  "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2020-02-07T13:52:29Z",
  "analyzeResult": {
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "errors": [{
      "code": "3003",
      "message": "OCR extraction error: [Wrong response code: FailedToDownloadImage. Message: Failed to download image from input URL..]"
    }]
  }
}
```

The image in the analyze request is located to an azure blob container btw. The other two methods like analyze layout and analyze receipt work fine with the same image URL.I couldnt find any info for the error code nor in the docs nor at the api definition.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

as a test, could you put your jpg file to a local file path and call the Analyze method?  This could be a workaround.

Comment: what you mean by local path?how will the api access the image?Actually i found out that the problem occurs when using the console.If you do the same same steps in ms flow, everything runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you set "useLabelFile" to true on the Train Custom Model, if you don't have any label or ocr files, this property should by false.